# Grails 3: is 'defaultValue' a valid constraint?

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

I've seen various posts that suggesting that as of Grails v2.2 you can have a constraint like:

```
static constraints = {
    minBedrooms defaultValue: 3
}
```

However, the documentation for constraints [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html) doesn't list defaultValue as a valid constraint entry.

Is it or is it not implemented in V3?  If not, and I want to set a default value for a field to an enum value, can I just declare it like this:

```
ContractStatusEnum contractStatus = ContractStatusEnum.Active
```

Comment: It's not a constraint, it's a mapping customization, and it sets the default value in the database, not the object in memory: http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html

Answer (score 0):

> Grails 3: is 'defaultValue' a valid constraint?

No, `defaultValue` is not a valid constraint.